# Label Properties at excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to program a general sub for my labels. I have the following code, but textAlign with centering does not work.

It only centers from the top but would like to have the text exactly in the middle of the label. Is there a function for this?

```
Sub SetLabelProperties()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ctrl As OLEObject

    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WorkFlow")

    For Each ctrl In ws.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(ctrl.Object) = "Label" Then
            With ctrl.Object
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .ForeColor = RGB(70, 70, 70)  
                .BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 0)
                .BorderColor = RGB(169, 169, 169)  
                .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleSingle
                .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter ' not working
                
            End With
            
        End If
    Next ctrl
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094639/212869

Comment: There isn't a property for vertical alignment. You may need to adjust the font size and lable height to get the expected result.